# Как вызвать несколько ключей с одинаковым именем в объекте?

Tags: javascript, объекты

Как вызвать несколько ключей с одинаковым именем в объекте?
Код:

```
let films = {
    name: "Терминатор", rating: 7, year: 1990, company: "Sony",
    name: "Человек паук", rating: 8, year: 2001, company: "Sony" 
}
```

Как вызвать сразу 2 ключа 'name' в объекте?

Comment: ключи - уникальны

Comment: А если через массив?

Comment: @Katsuroo можно в обьекте создать свойство `names` которое будет масивом и туда напихать сколько угодно нужных обьектов

Comment: нужно заменить `{}` на `[]`, и вокруг каждой строки поставить `{}`

Answer (score 0):

Как уже посоветовали выше, есть смысл представить это в виде массива с объектами. Где каждый объект будет содержать информацию о конкретном фильме по ключам.
Перебрать их можно обыкновенным циклом.
В случае с forEach в аргумент item попадает каждый элемент массива. Обратиться к свойствам объекта и проводить с ними различные манипуляции можно с помощью item.name, item.rating.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: 'Человек',
    rating: 6
  },
  {
    name: 'Паук',
    rating: 3
  }
];

arr.forEach((item) => {
  console.log('forEach', item);
  console.log('forEach-name', item.name);
  console.log('forEach-rating', item.rating);
});
```